# Problem: Abstract Algebra (3rd Edition) Dummit and Foote, Chapter 3, 3.1, pg 85

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Problem: *Abstract Algebra* (3rd Edition), by Dummit and Foote, Chapter 3, 3.1, pg 85:

The problem is stated as follows:

**Define $f: R^* \to \{1,-1\}$ by letting $f(x)$ be $\frac x{|x|}$. Describe
the fibers of $f$ and prove that $f$ is a homomorphism.**

Dummit and Foote define fibers only in the context of homomorphisms. As in we need to first prove that $f$ is a homomorphism, and then we proceed to deduce the fibers over the elements belonging to the image.

Definition of a "fiber" in Dummit and Foote: "If $F$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to a group $H$ recall that the fibers of $F$ are the sets of elements of $G$ projecting to single elements of H".

The answer is straightforward, but what is bothering me is the following:

**1. Are fibers only associated with homomorphisms? What if a certain function from a group $H$ to $G$ is not a homomorphism, I may still be able to define a similar idea of the "fiber" right?**

**2. Also, why do I need that the function be a homomorphism in order to define the concept of a fiber?**

**3. Can I first deduce the fibers associated with the given function, and THEN prove that the given function is a homomorphism?**

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Your questions are phrased as an isolated problems, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The domain of your $f$ must be $\Bbb R^*,$ not $\Bbb R.$ That said, 1) right 2) you don't 3) yes.

Comment: @AnneBauval: Thank you so much!! Grateful!

Comment: @Shaun: Forgive me, but I have to disagree. I have already explicitly mentioned that I am not seeking a solution to the problem . I have have also given more than sufficient context with regards to the question(s) that has/have been troubling me [indeed, I have even quoted lines from the textbook so as to provide as much context and information as I can]. Lastly, what I am requesting are not solutions to problems but answers -- simple and direct -- to three very related questions, and hence not isolated.

Comment: @Shaun: Furthermore, since the answers that I am requesting are conceptual in nature, it does strongly imply that I have thought a lot about the problem. In other words, the very nature of my questions -- not problems -- implies the work I have put in trying to understand certain subtleties of the problem's solution.

So, I still fail to understand where have I run afoul with the rules of this forum. I fear I have been summarily downvoted, and those who have downvoted the post have not read the post.

Comment: Actually, the concept of [fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(mathematics)) is more general and applicable to any function $f\colon A\to B$ for sets $A,B$. The fibers of $f$ are precisely the preimage sets $f^{-1}(b):=\{a\in A\mid f(a)=b\}$ for $b\in B$, closely related to the concept of [pullback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback).

Comment: Questions, queries, problems - whatever you call them - need to be asked one at a time, regardless of how "conceptual" they are. You need context, for, otherwise, the site will be (even more) flooded with low quality, "do my homework" questions. No exceptions. No excuses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Dummit and Foote define fibers only in the context of homomorphisms.

This assertion is incorrect. Looking at my copy (Second Edition), pages 1 and 2:

> We shall use the notation $f\colon A\to B$ or $A\stackrel{f}{\to}B$ to denote a function $f$ from $A$ to $B$
>
> [...]
>
> For each subset $C$ of $B$, the set
> $$f^{-1}(C)=\{a\in A\mid f(a)\in C\}$$
> consisting of the elements of $A$ mapping into $C$ under $f$ is called the *preimage* or *inverse image* of $C$ under $f$. **For each $b\in B$, the preimage of $\{b\}$ under $f$ is called the fiber of $f$ over $b$.** [emphasis added].

This happens in the book before the introduction of the term "homomorphism", whose first occurrence seems to be in page 37.

By the way, I found the definition of fiber through the complicated and arcane process of *checking the index of the book*.

Comment: For the record, I've not seen "fiber" in the context of basic algebra before, though it clearly could only have meant preimage.  The authors are trying to suggest terminology consistent with topology and other categories.  No big issue since they defined it on pages 1 and 2 but look at the fuss it caused.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 I've certainly seen "fiber" used in other contexts. But here we have an OP who is being very, very persnickety here and elsewhere about use of terminology and notation, but doesn't tell us which edition of the book they are looking at and apparently can't check the index to see if it is defined elsewhere...

Comment: (+1), thanks for for the final sentence ;-) I wonder why my comment was deleted, I repeat it.

Comment: @AnneBauval It must have gotten flags.  Enough flags, it auto-deletes. Probably the same folk(s) who downvoted.

Comment: Hmm, those who found it "unfriendly or unkind" may have not understood my approval of your humorous but polite call to order to the OP.